# Fast fulltext comparation of two databases

Tags: full-text-search

I have 2 databases with product data.  Data in both presented in third normal form and tables have the following fields:

**id**, **FullName**, **AttributeName**, **AttributeValue**

So, there are many rows (attributes) for every id (product).

I need to find relevant products (with relevance value) from first DB for every product from second DB. Comparation should be structed (I need to compare both names and attributes).
Comparation by **FullName** and **AttributeName** (both are strings) between two products should be performed using fulltext search or some kind of fuzzy comparation (may be some embeddings).

I have tens of millions products in first database and millions of products in second. Products could be added or deleted from both databases. If we had new product in first database, we need to calculate relevance of every product in second database with it, and if we had new product in second one we could perform search query on all records in first one.

Because of number of products, I look towards fulltext search engines like Sphinx, ElasticSearch of Apache Solr.

But question is could I calculate relevance of all products in second DB with some new products in first DB not performing "bruteforce querying" (perform  search using every product from second DB as query)? May be there is some "inverted relevance search" in such engines, or some else engine.

I use Python as a programming language in my system, so engine should have API I could use from Python.

Answer (score 0):

More than a month late, but if you are still on this, maybe you can check this - [Manticore Percolate](https://manual.manticoresearch.com/Creating_an_index/Local_indexes/Percolate_index)

I am not sure if I understand your question properly.